# php base64 decode function is unable to decode base64 image string

Tags: php, javascript, image, xhtml, base64

since `ie7` & `ie8` are unable to decode base64 image string by default, i was looking for an alternative way to do it. after googleing about the issue i have found a good tutorial at http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/ .

as far as i understand the process of decode consists of two short scripts which are as following:

A. **php base64 decode function**

named as `base64.php` as guided by the author

```
<?php
$data = split(";", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
$type = $data[0];
$data = split(",", $data[1]);
header("Content-type: ".$type);
echo base64_decode($data[1]);
?>
```

B. **javascript**

which shall be inserted within the head tag of the page where base64 image string shall be embedded and which finally shall pass the image string to `base64.php` for processing & decoding.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// a regular expression to test for Base64 data
var BASE64_DATA = /^data:.*;base64/i;
// path to the PHP module that will decode the encoded data
var base64Path = "base64.php";
function fixBase64(img) {
  // check the image source
  if (BASE64_DATA.png(img.src)) {
    // pass the data to the PHP routine
    img.src = base64Path + "?" + img.src.slice(5);
  }
};
// fix images on page load
onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    fixBase64(document.images[i]);
  }
};
</script>
```

unfortunately php base64 decode function is unable to decode the image string  to `ie7` & `ie8` in my case.

my doc type is `DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional` & `charset=utf-8`.

any idea what's going wrong here?

**demo links:**

base64-string-without-php-decoder: http://silentpond.eu5.org/base64-string-without-php-decoder.php

base64-string-with-php-decoder: http://silentpond.eu5.org/base64-string-with-php-decoder.php

thanks,

Comment: How big are your images? I think you might run into an issue with the length of the url with this method.

Comment: @datasage my image size is 30.1KB and this size is supported by `ie` for decoding base64 image string.

Comment: hmm! it seems that my image produces 41138 bytes url which is far high than the accepted limit but although the url doesn't contain name pair value it is transferred in the header and `data URI resource` for the image shouldn't be greater than `4,096 bytes` in this case. `reference:` http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688188

Comment: Data urls don't make sense for large images. You loose the advantage of caching. They make the most sense for images in which the cost of requesting the image is greater than the cost of downloading it.

Comment: yes, that's true that image aren't cached in this case but i like the smoothness of load flow this way which is well supported by smart devices like smart phones.

Comment: If you get an image to cache correctly (Cache-Control, Expires headers), it will load smoothly. It wont even create another request.

Answer (score 2):

In IE, at least with version 8 and earlier. The max length of url is about 2047 bytes. More information can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427